# Adding FieldFile objects without form in django

Tags: python, django, models

I have a django model as follow:

```
class XML(ExtensibleModel):
     xml = models.FileField(upload_to='xml',blank=True, null=True)
```

Here, I store some xmls files. Before, I submited the files to my server by a html form. Now, I copy the files by ssh, and I want to keep storing the new files in this model. The problem is that I can't do it. I tried with the follow code

```
f = open(FILENAME,'r')
A = XML(xml = f)
A.save()
```

but, I get this error:

```
'file' object has no attribute '_committed'
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [django file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/files/file/) instead of just an open file.

```
from django.core.files import File
...
f = open(FILENAME,'r')
A=XML()
A.xml.save(filename, File(f), save=True)
A.save()
```

Comment: Thanks Kevan S. That's the solution for my problem

Comment: If you could mark it as answered that would be great :)